# Understanding time series MAPE is calculated

Tags: r

Suppose I simulate some data in R:

```
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)

set.seed(123)

weeks <- rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-01"), by = "week"), each = 1)
counts <- rpois(length(weeks), lambda = 50)
df <- data.frame(Week = as.character(weeks), Count = counts)

# Convert Week column to Date format
df$Week <- as.Date(df$Week)

# Create a time series object
ts_data <- ts(df$Count, frequency = 52, start = c(year(min(df$Week)), 1))
```

Then, I fit a time series model to this data:

```
 fit_arima <- auto.arima( ts_data , seasonal = TRUE, lambda = "auto")
```

From here, I can see different error calculations, such as the MAPE (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error):

```
Series: ts_data 
ARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0)[52] with non-zero mean 
Box Cox transformation: lambda= 1.999927 

Coefficients:
        sar1       mean
      0.0350  1271.3883
s.e.  0.0402    13.7245

sigma^2 = 120100:  log likelihood = -4933.31
AIC=9872.62   AICc=9872.65   BIC=9886.18

Training set error measures:
                     ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set -0.4759905 6.930849 5.453443 -3.033185 11.53007 0.7088119 -0.01118025
```

**My Question:** I am trying to understand how the MAPE (11.53007) was calculated.

Specifically, given the data I used and the "fit_arima" object - how can I manually replicate this calculation in R to see how 11.53007 was obtained (e.g. extract the intermediate calculations and then calculate it myself)?

Here is my current understanding:

- The model is fit to the entire dataset - after this is done, we no longer retrain the model
- After this, the model is given the first data point and predicts the second point. The error is calculated and recorded
- Now, the model is given the first two data points and predicts the third point. The error is calculated and recorded
- Now, the model is given the first three data points and predicts the fourth point. The error is calculated and recorded.
- This is repeated for all points ... finally, the MAPE is the average of all these errors.

Can someone please help me understand how R is calculating this MAPE number?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe if you run `forecast:::trainingaccuracy` you'll see the code used to calculate this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAPE is computed according to the definition in [Hydman et al. book](https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html) and using all data in the training set (ts_data, 679 data points).

From the fit_arima model, you compute the difference between original data and forecasted one (e_t), divide by the origial data (to obtain variation) and multiply by 100 to get it as percentage. MAPE is the mean of the absolute value of the variation.

```r
fit_arima <- auto.arima( ts_data , seasonal = TRUE, lambda = "auto")

accuracy(fit_arima)[5]
#> [1] 11.53007

err <- fit_arima$x - fit_arima$fitted
variations <- err / fit_arima$x * 100
MAPE <- mean(abs(variations)) 
MAPE
#> [1] 11.53007
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I posted a similar question here - can you please take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76939820/r-understanding-how-the-fitted-function-works thanks!