# R: Understanding how the fitted() function works

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

**Step 1:** I have the following data that I simulated:

```
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)

set.seed(123)

weeks <- rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-01"), by = "week"), each = 1)
counts <- rpois(length(weeks), lambda = 50)
df <- data.frame(Week = as.character(weeks), Count = counts)

# Convert Week column to Date format
df$Week <- as.Date(df$Week)

# Create a time series object
ts_data <- ts(df$Count, frequency = 52, start = c(year(min(df$Week)), 1))
```

**Step 2:** I then fit a time series model to this data:

```
 fit_arima <- auto.arima( ts_data , seasonal = TRUE, lambda = "auto")
```

**Step 3:** I then used the `fitted()` function on the resulting model:

```
# Extract fitted values from fit_arima object
fitted_values <- fit_arima$fitted

# Calculate MAPE
#mape <- mean(abs((ts_data - fitted_values) / ts_data)) * 100
```

**My Question:** I am trying to understand how the `fit_arima$fitted` is being used to calculate these fitted values.

For example - suppose Step 1 and Step 2 have been performed. From here, how can I  manually calculate the vector of the fitted values in R? **In the end, I would like to manually calculate this vector and show that it is the same as the original vector.**

Thanks!

Comment: `fitted()` doesnt calculate anything, its just a generic function that extracts the fitted values from the model object. You can see this by `all.equal(fit_arima$fitted, fitted_values)` returns `TRUE`

Comment: @jpsmith: thank you so much for your reply! do you know how the "fitted" values are being calculated within the arima model itself?

Comment: I think this might work? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/343923/how-to-repoduce-the-fitted-values-from-a-forecastarima-in-r-by-hand

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32575/computing-the-fitted-value-for-the-first-observation-in-a-time-series

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question as you would like to know how to create the fitted
model values from the arima model you has generated.

Before I show how to generate those fitted value from the model, a couple of
comments to the data you have generated `ts_data`

1. The time series `ts_data` can be written as
   $y_t = \psi_t$, where the noise term is the poison distribution with
   $\lambda = 50$ . Taking into account that for this value of $\lambda$, Poisson
   distribution can be approximated by a Gaussian distribution with $\mu = \lambda$
   and $\sigma = \sqrt(\lambda)$, your equation can be written as $y_t = \mu + \epsilon_t$,
   with $\epsilon$ an gaussian white noise with $\sigma = \sqrt(50)$.
   The Arima model equivalent to a white noise is (0,0,0), as shown in the first
   part of output of `auto.arima()`-
2. When calling the `auto_arima()` function, you set `seasonal = TRUE`, which
   means that on top of the standard ARIMA you will run another ARIMA for the
   seasonal part. According to the definition of `ts_data`, frequency is 52. Also,
   you set `lambda = "auto"` that means that before fitting the time series, data
   may be transformed using Box-Cox transformation. Indeed, teh output of the model
   tells you that such a transformation was done with $\lambda= 1.999927$. By
   pure chance, the seasonal component of the ARIMA becomes (1,0,0), instead of the
   expected (0,0,0).

To reproduce the fitted values, `fitted(fit_arima)`, which is equivalent to
`fit_arima$fitted` as pointed out in some of the comments, we will do the
following:

1. Transform the original series using Box-Cox transformation

```
ts_transformed <- ts(BoxCox(ts_data, fit_arima$lambda), frequency = 52, 
  start = c(year(min(df$Week)), 1))
```

2. Apply the seasonal ARIMA model (1,0,0) with the parameters generated in the
   output of the model (sar1 = 0.0350 and mean = 1271.3883)

```
mu <- coef(fit_arima)[2]
mu
#> intercept 
#>  1271.388
sar1 <- coef(fit_arima)[1]
sar1
#>       sar1 
#> 0.03501978

y_fit <- c(rep(mu, 52), # first part equal to mean for one period 52
  mu * (1 - sar1) + sar1 * ts_transformed[1:(679-52)])
```

The second part is the model equation for seasonal ARIMA model (1,0,0):
$y_t = (1-sar1) * mu + sar1 * y_{t-52}$. Main reference for all I explained here
is [Hyndman, R.J., & Athanasopoulos, G. (2018) Forecasting: principles and practice, 2nd edition, OTexts: Melbourne, Australia. OTexts.com/fpp2. Accessed on 2023-08-26](https://otexts.com/fpp2/)

3. Finally we revert the Box-Cox transformation to obtain the fitted
   values reported in fit_arima object

```
y_fit_back <- InvBoxCox(y_fit, fit_arima$lambda)
ts_fit_back <- ts(y_fit_back, frequency = 52, start = c(2010, 1))
```

`y_fit_back` series is the same as `fit_arima$fitted` as you can see in this
plot

```
plot(fit_arima$fitted)
points(ts_fit_back, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>